# Add Compile function in a code to speed up the execution

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, compile

I have a code

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"];
h[a1_, l_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   a1 l Exp[-l  y0] (1 - Exp[-l  y0])^(a1 - 1), {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}];
ParallelTable[
  data = RandomVariate[h[3, 1.5], 100];
  lnL1[a1_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] := 
   Block[{}, LogLikelihood[h[a1, l], data]];
  e2 = NMaximize[{lnL1[a1, l], {a1 > 0}, {l > 0}}, {a1, l}, 
    Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"], {5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This code works fine, but takes too much time for huge replications. To save time I know `Compile` function execute the code in C. But I am unable to add `Compile` function in that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for manual compilation. It's possible to write the code in such a way that NMaximize automatically compiles the likelihood function for you. It will also be able to compute the gradient symbolically, which allows for faster convergence and higher precision.

```
h[a1_, l_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   a1 l Exp[-l y0] (1 - Exp[-l y0])^(a1 - 1), {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}];
data = RandomVariate[h[3, 1.5], 100];
(*Your code*)

logPDF[a1_, l_, x_] = PowerExpand@Log@Refine[PDF[h[a1, l], x], x > 0]
(*PowerExpand often results in a simpler log-likelihood function*)

logLikelihood = Total@logPDF[a1, l, data]
(*Note how three of its four terms each appear only once*)

NMaximize[{logLikelihood, {a1 > 0, l > 0}}, {a1, l}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.131648,{-94.9113,{a1->3.18393,l->1.59988}}}*)

transformedParameters = logLikelihood /. {a1 -> Exp[loga1], l -> Exp[logl]};
FindMaximum[transformedParameters, {loga1, logl}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.019304,{-94.9113,{loga1->1.15812,logl->0.469928}}}*)
(*Unconstrained optimization is much faster*)
```

Edit: I forgot Mathematica has a built-in function specifically for this task. It's not as fast, though.

```
FindDistributionParameters[data, h[a1, l], {{a1, 1}, {l, 1}}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.066339, {a1->3.18393,l->1.59988}}*)
```

Edit 2: **C Compiled Functions**

There are basically two approaches: accumulate log-PDFs sample-by-sample, or incrementally compute the likelihood function with vectorized operations on the dataset as a whole. The first approach is cache-friendly, the second utilizes fast SIMD instructions. It's hard to tell which one will work better on the real problem, so I'll implement both here.

```
logPDFfunction = Function[{a1, l, x}, Evaluate@PowerExpand@Log@Refine[PDF[h[a1, l], x], x > 0]]
(*Workaround for a weird bug preventing unpure functions from being inlined on some systems. Investigation in progress. Thanks to @Michael E2 for pointing this out.*)

logLikelihoodC1 = Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {l, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{i, s = 0.},
    Do[
     s += logPDFfunction[a1, l, x[[i]]],
     {i, Length[x]}];
    s],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

logLikelihoodC2 = Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {l, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}},
   Total@logPDFfunction[a1, l, x],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

objective[function_, a1_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, data_] := function[a1, l, data];

NMaximize[{objective[logLikelihoodC1, a1, l, data], a1 > 0, l > 0}, {a1, l}, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.061932, {-73.9552, {a1 -> 3.77946, l -> 1.99648}}}*)

NMaximize[{objective[logLikelihoodC2, a1, l, data], a1 > 0, l > 0}, {a1, l}, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.055937, {-73.9552, {a1 -> 3.77946, l -> 1.99648}}}*)
```

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Even if we compare only the execution time of your `NMaximize` to that of `FindDistributionParameters`, the built-in is twice as fast as your solution, isn't it? (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB, FindDistributionParameters uses unconstrained FindMaximum by default, so it's fair to compare it to FindMaximum with objective function constructed by hand as above. The magic of PowerExpand made a 3-fold difference! To be absolutely fair, I should have compared reparametrized FindDistributionParameters to reparametrized FindMaximum, but that would only increase the performance gap.

Comment: @aooiiii I have customize likelihood and 'FindDistributionParameter' did not work for it. Secondly because it is simple example 'FindMaximum' works fine and better in speed against 'NMaximise'. But I have experience in case of customize or complex likelihood 'FindMaximum' having more problem of convergence. That's why I am interested in 'Compile' function.

Comment: @SAAN, oh. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think you want `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` to avoid call-backs to the kernel to evaluate `logPDFfunction`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I know about that option, but even with it turned on, logLikelihoodC1 is about 60 times slower with "unpure" logPDF. Do you think it's a bug worth reporting?

Comment: I didn't try the whole problem, but just evaluating `logLikelihoodC1` and `logLikelihoodC2` is roughly two and one of orders of magnitude faster (resp.) with the option.

Comment: `NMaximize[{objective[logLikelihoodC1, a1, l, data], a1 > 0, 
  l > 0}, {a1, l}, Method -> "NelderMead"]` is about 3–4 times faster (with inlining) than with `logLikelihood`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, this is all very weird. I'll need some time to investigate the bug further as its behavior depends on that option value, function purity, input size and whether the code is running inside NMaximize or on its own. My system is Mathematica 12.1 for Linux. Ugh, my head is spinning.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using 12.1 on a Mac, 2.8GHz 4-core i7. I've been assuming you know about ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint@logLikelihoodC1`` and `MainEvaluate` (but I mention it just in case).  Consider omitting `CompilationTarget -> "C"`.